in MUI Table Not deleting the specified row from current page
Please find below Link for live
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muidatagrid.tsx,POC.css,index.tsx
code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muidatagrid.tsx,POC.css,index.tsx
from the Live code of an example Whenever i delete row in middle of rows or first row or middle of row on current page, it is being deleting row only last row from current page , Even though if i delete any row of middle it is been always deleting last row only on current page .Therefore issue here was On current page if delete or remove any middle row it always keep on deleting the last row only?
Current behavior:
Whenever i delete row in middle of rows or first row or any row other than last row on current page, it is being deleting row only last row from current page ,
The following screenshot where highlighted row I'm trying to delete it

Whenever i delete the particular row then it should only delete that particular row only.

Whenever i delete row in middle of rows or first row or any row other than last row on current page, then it should only delete that particular row only on current page.

This behavior is pretty common when relying on the index as the key identifier for the row.  Each row of data should be represented by an object in state with its own unique identifier that doesn't potentially change on each render.

@David : do you have any solution to mitigate it?

How do you currently track the state of the data displayed in the table rows?  What is the unique identifier for any given row?

i would tracking each row with{page * rowsPerPage + index}?  and  data displayed in the table rows? how can we achieve this can we add any id to data like filed and is it possible  to track? please suggest me do you any idea of it tracking displayed rows in table?

Why specifically would you not want to track the rows of data as objects in state?  Consider this from React's perspective... You have rows 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.  If you use the index to track state then no matter which one you delete, what you have remaining are rows 0, 1, 2, and 3.  This is by design, because your only identifier is the array index.  So my suggestion is that you use meaningful data instead of the array index.

So my suggestion is that you use meaningful data instead of the array index.? do you have sample code like how i can use it?

Sample code for how to track data in state is something that can be found in pretty much any React tutorial.  The point is to start with your data.  What structure of data is being represented by this table?  What array of objects would hold that information?  Outside the context of React or any other UI, given only that structure of data, how would you uniquely identify any given record in that data?  Once you've decided on that, you have what you're looking for.  An array of objects to iterate over for displaying the rows, and a unique identifier to use as the key.

I'll get back you with more details Thanks

There are at least two issues with your current code. If we look at the following code:
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, name: 'nestedArray' });

return (
  <>
    {/* ... */}
    {fields
      .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
      .map((item, index) => (
        <TableRow key={page * rowsPerPage + index}>
          {/* ... */}
          <IconButton
            onClick={() => {
              remove(index);
            }}
            aria-label="delete"
            size="small"
          >
             <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
          {/* ... */}
        </TableRow>
      ))
    }
    {/* ... */}
  </>
);

Your main issue is that removing some row removes the last row instead. This is because you are using the index as (part of the) key. This can often lead to these kinds of issues.
Here is a relatively quick explanation if you're interested in why.

Say index i is associated with component c. If you delete the element at index i, all the other elements after it will shift down to a lower index. In the next render index i is still present (though now associated with another array element), but React still associates index i with component c. Therefore component c is not unmounted. Say that we had an array with indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3. If we delete array element with index 1, then the element at index 2 will shift to index 1, and the element at index 3 will shift to index 2. So if react was to re-render the component the only key missing is (index) 3, therefore the final component is unmounted.

useFieldArray automatically generates ids for all items inside the array, this id should be used as the column key instead. It's unique for the array element, and it doesn't shift like indices do. The documentation tells us the following:

Rules

useFieldArray automatically generates a unique identifier named id which is used for key prop. For more information why this is
required: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
The field.id (and not index) must be added as the component key to prevent re-renders breaking the fields:
// ✅ correct:
{fields.map((field, index) => <input key={field.id} ... />)}

// ❌ incorrect:
{fields.map((field, index) => <input key={index} ... />)}




So to solve your issue, use <TableRow key={item.id}> instead.

Secondly <IconButton onClick={() => remove(index)}> will also remove the wrong element if you remove any element that's not on the first page. This is because you .slice() the array beforehand. You should offset this by the page just like you do in a lot of other places. So this should be:
<IconButton onClick={() => remove(page * rowsPerPage + index)}>


Secondly <IconButton onClick={() => remove(index)}> will also remove the wrong element if you remove any element that's not on the first page. This is because you .slice() the array beforehand. You should offset this by the page just like you do in a lot of other places. So this should be:? can you please me this point with an simple example? i was not clear it ?thanks

Let me sketch a scenario which highlights the issue, then you might be able to see the problem better. Assume you have a list of 7 elements (5 per page). You press the delete button on the first element of the second page. What row will be deleted? With your current code that would be the first row of the first page, not the second page. Why? Because index in .slice().map() is 0 whereas the index that you want to remove in the fields array is 5 (6th field, aka 1st element of 2nd page).

in .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage) from code we are generating the rows per page based on rows and initial of page is0 and rows per page is as 5 let us consider this example I've 20 elements,on each page will generate 5 rows till next three pages .if i see the index of each row on every page would be like on 1st page index 0 , 1 2, 3 .5 and 2nd page index is 0,1,2,3,4,and 3rd index is 01234and finally 4th page index is 01234.my requirement is i want to have index should for each row on 1st page would be like 012 34 then continue like 2nd page56789 like

(continue from above comment due character left )  like above said 3rd page like 10 11 12 13 14 and finally 4th page 15 16 17 18 19....like i want make indexs for that   .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)  here what logic i can apply?please let me know?

It's not possible with just slice(), since it creates a new array containing the selected 5 elements. Arrays start with index 0 and go up to the length of the array. A simple solution would be to just re-assign index as the first statement in the map() function. .map((item, index) => { index += page * rowsPerPage; return (<TableRow key={item.id}>...</TableRow>); })

it works well ..but can we add row before a row and after a row? is it possible to achieve this scenario? if you could help it would be a great learning thing for me ... here from the live code i want insert a row after any row and also i want insert a row before any row? how can we achieve that?

Seems like you already found the solution. You should use the insert helper returned from useFieldArray: <button type="button" onClick={() => insert(index, { name: '', ... })}>before</button> to insert an index before a given row, and index + 1 to insert it after a given row. In both cases index represents the index of fields, not the index of the .slice() result.

I've one more query can please give some idea about my ask?

const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
// Include displayOrder in nestedArray items
const dataWithDisplayOrder = {
...data,
nestedArray: data.nestedArray.map((item, index) => ({
...item,
displayOrder: index,
})),
};  console.log(dataWithDisplayOrder.nestedArray);
useMutation({
mutationFn: addTodo,
onError: (error, variables, context) => {
},onSettled: (data, error, variables, context) => {
// Error or success... doesn't matter!
},

onSuccess: (responseId, variables, context) => {
now i'll reset t the nestedArray
here on success data get response as id
now call backend service fetch the saved data using response id
assign fetched saved data to nestedArray ? My was here how to assign saved datathat fetched from api call to Netsed Array?
},     This is my ask?

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. One thing that does stand out from the given code is that you use useMutation inside onSubmit. This does not follow the React rules of hooks guidelines and will (if not already) create issues. You also never use the useMutation return value. I suggest reading through the React rules of hooks since it offers very important React knowledge that you need in every React project. (1/2)

Then checkout the TanStack Query Mutations guide to get a better understanding of the useMutation hook. (2/2)

Could please suggest me that the way i used  React query functions call and definition in live code examples  are valid to use? ? was that good to use or Do you have any best recommendations?

@ashokreddy Why are you trying to destroy this answer? This is the 4th time now you edited the answer and remove like 90% of what I've written without adding to it.
